# Get postfix to send emails to the mail server

Tags: ubuntu, postfix

I have 2 servers. One is a fully configured mail server that receives emails from any sender. I also have my web server that has apps like logwatch and tripwire installed and they all installed postfix on the webserver. Now tripwire is configured to email me@mahamed91.tk but the webserver keeps sending that email to a local account with the same name, but when i configure it to email it to me@mail.mahamed91.tk it sends it to the mail server and I don't want that happening.

How do I configure it to send to the mail server instead of the local account? and why is do I have to add mail subdomain to send it to the mail server instead of the local account. It doesn't seem to be quering the DNS properly.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have 2 machines, one of them is configured as a mail server, the second a web server that needs to send you alerts.  You have the second server configured with postfix but it's not forwarding mail to the mail server so that you get the notifications?

On the web server, drill down to the /etc/postfix directory and modify the main.cf file.
in the relayhost section add:

```
relayhost = (name of mailserver)
```

save the file and restart the postfix service with `postfix restart`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like postfix in your webserver was configured so it thinks that mahamed91.tk was local domain. Check the main.cf  configuration of web server, especially in `mydestination` parameter. You need to ensure that parameter doesn't contain  mahamed91.tk

If above solution doesn't work, post the output of command `postconf -n` from webserver.